# what is an acceptable level of kjournald process time on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu-8.04, kjournald

I was running `top` on my server and noticed `kjournald` seemed (to me) to have a high cpu time.  My server has been up for ~21 days and I have never noticed triple-digit minutes usage of `kjournald` before.
[image: kjournald on top]

Is this normal of Ubuntu 8.04 or do I need to worry about something going wrong on my system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`kjournald` is invoked pretty much on all disk operations, so it's not that strange that it has a lot of CPU time, specially if your server has many write operations. Nothing to worry about, IMO.

Long explanation: `kjournald` is the kernel thread responsible for journaling on `ext3` file systems. You will have one per mounted `ext3` FS. On busy hosts, where there are many disk writes commited to the journal and then to the disk and depending on the journaling strategy, it can be quite resource hungry. Take a look on [this doc](http://www.redhat.com/support/wpapers/redhat/ext3/) to read a little more about it.